# How to connect 2 faces?

Tags: faces

I am new to blender, and tried to make my sword based on my mind. And I found a problem...

I want to connect the center/middle cube to the lower sword part(the small gap between the sword), but I don't know how. I tried to connect it, but it will be intersect with each other and unable to delete the area inside it(at least I tried). I tried to use boolean method, but it  got an error(might be my drawing's problem). Can you teach me how to fix/do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do as Benjamin says, use, in Edit mode, the **Loop cut and slide** tool (<kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>) on the biggest lower cube and snap the lines to the upper cube.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit mode, and on edge mode, select the edges you want to create a face with and hit the F key.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to figure it how to combine it into a 90 degree edge cube between the middle cube and the added faces.